# read the excel file in directory using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to read the excel files in directory  if there is a file with specific name And then do some data related operations. But firstly I have a problem to read the files with pandas

```
import os
import pandas as pd

for filename in os.listdir(my_path):
    if filename.startswith('PB orders Dec'):
        dec=pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name='Raw data')
```

> error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PB orders December.xlsb'

But when I run this code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
    
    for filename in os.listdir(my_path):
        if filename.startswith('PB orders Dec'):
        print(filename)
```

result is the existing file name in directory : **PB orders December.xlsb**

How can I read a specific file in directory based on the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory is missing when you `read_excel`, you only point to the file as you showed with the print.

You need to rebuild the full path with for instance, [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

for filename in os.listdir(my_path):
    if filename.startswith('PB orders Dec'):
        dec = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(my_path, filename), sheet_name='Raw data')
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the directory: `path = os.path.join(my_path, filename)`, then `pd.read_excel(path, ...)`:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

for filename in os.listdir(my_path):
    if filename.startswith('PB orders Dec'):
        path = os.path.join(my_path, filename)
        dec = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Raw data')
```

Comment: after installing fsspec, i get new error OSError: File contains no valid workbook part

Comment: it is the extension problem. with xlsx it works but with xlsb no